# How to flatten a union type of objects

Tags: typescript

I have the following union type:

```
type Test =
  | {
      type: 'Union'
      items: Array<
        | { type: 'Number' }
        | { type: 'String' }
        | { type: 'Union'; items: Array<{ type: 'Number' } | { type: 'Boolean' }> }
      >
    }
  | { type: 'Date' }
```

And I would like the result to be:

```
type Result = 
  | { type: 'Number' }
  | { type: 'String' }
  | { type: 'Boolean' }
  | { type: 'Date' }
```

The following doesn't work because of the circular reference limitation:

```
type Flatten<T> = T extends { type: 'Union'; items: unknown[] }
                  ? Flatten<T['items'][number]>
                  : T
```

Is it possible to solve using an interface or another alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is (as of TS3.5) [no supported technique](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980#issuecomment-421354117) to do a recursive conditional type function in general.  It is generally okay if the circularity involves pushing types down into nested properties, but pulling types *out* of nested properties is not supported.  All the "clever" tricks I've tried (or seen tried) to fool the compiler into accepting such things have ended in sadness.

Generally what I do when I want a recursive type like this is to pick some reasonable depth of recursion at which to bail out.  In this case, how deeply nested are you expecting the `T` to typically be in `Flatten<T>`... let's say six layers deep at maximum?  Well, in that case, we can unroll the circular type into a series of non-circular types that hit a brick wall at the end:

```
type Flatten<T> = T extends { type: 'Union'; items: unknown[] } ? Flatten1<T['items'][number]> : T;
type Flatten1<T> = T extends { type: 'Union'; items: unknown[] } ? Flatten2<T['items'][number]> : T;
type Flatten2<T> = T extends { type: 'Union'; items: unknown[] } ? Flatten3<T['items'][number]> : T;
type Flatten3<T> = T extends { type: 'Union'; items: unknown[] } ? Flatten4<T['items'][number]> : T;
type Flatten4<T> = T extends { type: 'Union'; items: unknown[] } ? Flatten5<T['items'][number]> : T;
type Flatten5<T> = T extends { type: 'Union'; items: unknown[] } ? Flatten6<T['items'][number]> : T;
type Flatten6<T> = T extends { type: 'Union'; items: unknown[] } ? FlattenX<T['items'][number]> : T;
type FlattenX<T> = T; // uh oh  bail out
```

That might be ugly, but it generally has manageable effects.  Let's see how it does with your types:

```
type Result = Flatten<Test>;
// type Result = { type: "Date"; } | { type: "Number"; } | 
// { type: "String"; } | { type: "Number"; } | { type: "Boolean"; }
```

Looks good to me.  Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Test%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'Union'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20items%3A%20Array%3C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20%7B%20type%3A%20'Number'%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20%7B%20type%3A%20'String'%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20%7B%20type%3A%20'Union'%3B%20items%3A%20Array%3C%7B%20type%3A%20'Number'%20%7D%20%7C%20%7B%20type%3A%20'Boolean'%20%7D%3E%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3E%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20%7B%20type%3A%20'Date'%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Flatten%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20%7B%20type%3A%20'Union'%3B%20items%3A%20unknown%5B%5D%20%7D%20%3F%20Flatten1%3CT%5B'items'%5D%5Bnumber%5D%3E%20%3A%20T%3B%0D%0Atype%20Flatten1%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20%7B%20type%3A%20'Union'%3B%20items%3A%20unknown%5B%5D%20%7D%20%3F%20Flatten2%3CT%5B'items'%5D%5Bnumber%5D%3E%20%3A%20T%3B%0D%0Atype%20Flatten2%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20%7B%20type%3A%20'Union'%3B%20items%3A%20unknown%5B%5D%20%7D%20%3F%20Flatten3%3CT%5B'items'%5D%5Bnumber%5D%3E%20%3A%20T%3B%0D%0Atype%20Flatten3%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20%7B%20type%3A%20'Union'%3B%20items%3A%20unknown%5B%5D%20%7D%20%3F%20Flatten4%3CT%5B'items'%5D%5Bnumber%5D%3E%20%3A%20T%3B%0D%0Atype%20Flatten4%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20%7B%20type%3A%20'Union'%3B%20items%3A%20unknown%5B%5D%20%7D%20%3F%20Flatten5%3CT%5B'items'%5D%5Bnumber%5D%3E%20%3A%20T%3B%0D%0Atype%20Flatten5%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20%7B%20type%3A%20'Union'%3B%20items%3A%20unknown%5B%5D%20%7D%20%3F%20Flatten6%3CT%5B'items'%5D%5Bnumber%5D%3E%20%3A%20T%3B%0D%0Atype%20Flatten6%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20%7B%20type%3A%20'Union'%3B%20items%3A%20unknown%5B%5D%20%7D%20%3F%20FlattenX%3CT%5B'items'%5D%5Bnumber%5D%3E%20%3A%20T%3B%0D%0Atype%20FlattenX%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Result%20%3D%20Flatten%3CTest%3E%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20type%20Result%20%3D%20%7B%20type%3A%20%22Date%22%3B%20%7D%20%7C%20%7B%20type%3A%20%22Number%22%3B%20%7D%20%7C%20%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%7B%20type%3A%20%22String%22%3B%20%7D%20%7C%20%7B%20type%3A%20%22Number%22%3B%20%7D%20%7C%20%7B%20type%3A%20%22Boolean%22%3B%20%7D%0D%0A)

Comment: What about this type: `type Flatten<T> = T extends { type: 'Union'; items: unknown[] }
  ? { [P in keyof T]: P extends 'items' ? Flatten<T[P][number]> : never }[keyof T]
  : T` ?

Comment: That’s one of the tricks; make the compiler think the recursion is being pushed down into a property (in a mapped type in your case) and then pull it out (looking up the property you pushed it down into).  It’s not supported.  It might *work* for your use case in your build on your current version of TS; but it might stop working when used in slightly different circumstances.  If, say, TS3.6 comes out and breaks it, and you report it as a regression; you’ll be told that what you’re doing is not supported. The issue I linked to in my answer has more details.

Comment: So... if it works for you and you are using it in your own code and can deal with the consequences if it stops working, great.  But if it’s going in production code other people are using or maintaining, the unfortunate official answer is something like “don’t do it”.